# How can I get a box shadow to start below a thick border?

Tags: css

I have this piece of CSS:

```
.ab-banner
{
    background-color: #212121;
    background-image: url(logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    text-align: right;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #4DD2FF;
}
```

which produces:

[image]

Adding this: `box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px #000;`

produces this:

[image]

If you look closely at the shadow, it starts in the middle of the border.  Increasing the border thickness causes the same behavior, so its not started at the layer's bottom.

How can I get the shadow to start from the bottom of the border?
I saw that you can do this by setting the border as a background image as done [here](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-border-background-boxshadow/#box-shadow), but is there no way to do this in CSS?  I can get around this by making the shadow larger, though, that is not what my design calls for.

This is what I'd like:

[image]

**EDIT:**
@StackOverFlow UI, you are right, this will work correctly.  Thank you for the example!  The reason why the shadow was appearing in the middle was because the style was applied both to the table itself as well as the row that it contained.  Removing that style class reference from one or the other would fix the issue.  This unearthed a deeper issue in the layout, beyond the scope of this question.  Accepting your answer as it is relevant.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, you will have to make your shadow bigger. Unless you start nesting elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have seems to be fine. Check this out, it is just that the shadow is deeper near the borders.By increasing the box-shadow property to a higher value, you can get what you want. http://liveweave.com/DkpyhE